# From Databricks, how to write Transient table to Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

How can I write a transient table to Snowflake?

Documentations always show writing permanent table to Snowflake, but not Transient.
How can I modify below code to make it a Transient table?

```
# Generate a simple dataset containing five values and write the dataset to Snowflake.
spark.range(5).write 
  .format("snowflake") 
  .options(**options) 
  .option("dbtable", "<snowflake-database>") 
  .save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The example in the question doesn't show how to create a table, but how to write to an existing table (`<snowflake-database>`).

Someone has created that table already - if you want that table to be a temporal one or a transient one, say so while creating it:

You can see in the docs sample code:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use#exporting-json-from-spark-to-snowflake

```java
    System.out.println("Create my_variant_table table");
    statement.executeUpdate("create or replace table my_variant_table(json VARIANT)");
```

Comment: I'm actually using Python instead of Scala, and the example I provided is writing a new table, not an existing table.  <snowflake-database> is any arbitrary name you want to give to the new table. The sample code you provided doesn't say create transient table. Transient is not the same as variant.